# Access messages in Outlook's 'Drafts' folder

Tags: macos, applescript, ms-office

I would like to use a message that is stored in the 'Drafts' folder as a template for other messages.  Unfortunately, I don't have the correct syntax:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

  -- locate the message
  set theMessage to the first message in mail folder drafts <== error: 'Can't make mail folder id 107 into type integer'

  -- show subject (testing)
  display dialog of the subject of theMessage

  -- for each contact with category 'foo'
    -- copy message
    -- add sender
    -- add first name to message's body
    -- set delivery date to 5 minutes in the future
    -- send message
  -- end loop

end tell
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected code:

```
-- locate the message
set theMessage to the first message in drafts

-- show subject (testing)
display dialog of the (subject of theMessage as text)
```